# Switch trava o comando ao entrar uma letra

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo um código que utiliza switch (pois o usuário não pode dar qualquer input) onde eu preciso que o usuário determine se `r0` vai ter o valor inteiro de 1 ou 2, qualquer outro número fará a pergunta ser refeita. O meu problema é quando é colocado uma letra, que faz com que o código fique em um loop travado, alguma sugestão para arrumar isso?

```
pergunta1() {
cin >> r0;
switch (r0){
    case 1:
        pergunta2();
    case 2:
        pergunta2();
    default:
        pergunta1();
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente você definiu a variável r0 como um inteiro. Defina a variável r0 como um caractere (char) e verifique se o que foi digitado é um caractere válido para seu programa, pelo que entendi de seu problema ou '1' ou '2', todos os demais são caracteres inválidos.

Answer (score 1):

Use um `stringstream` para receber `cin` pois o stream processa os caracteres um a um e interrompe o processo se houver um caractere invalido de acordo com o tipo pedido.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void pergunta2(void ){
  std::cout << "pergunta2" << std::endl;   
}

void pergunta1(void ) {

      std::cout << "pergunta1" << std::endl; 

      string input;
      getline(cin, input);
      stringstream buffer(input);

      //std::stringstream buffer;
      // Descomente a próxima linha caso r0 ainda não tenha sido declarado
       int r0; 

      //buffer << std::cin;
      buffer >> r0; 

      switch (r0){
          case 1:  // fall through      
          case 2:
              pergunta2();
              break;
          default:
              pergunta1();
       }
   }

int main()
{

    pergunta1();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: esse código nem compila...

Comment: Modifiquei o código de forma a facilitar para quem tenha dificuldades com streams.

Comment: não existe vantagem em trocar cin (istream) por buffer (stringstream) nesta sua segunda versão...quando você faz "cin >> r0" e "buffer >> r0" o efeito é o mesmo

Comment: @zentrunix `cin >> r0` e `buffer >> r0` possuem efeitos bem diferentes. Leia as duas primeiras linhas.

Comment: a diferença no comportamento em sua versão é causada pelo getline (e não por "buffer >> r0"), que consome a linha errada quando é digitada uma letra ao invés de um número, mas neste caso a função pergunta1 é chamada **recursivamente**, e **outras** cópias de input e buffer são criada...me desculpe, mas esta não é uma solução aceitável...o que deve ser feito para resolver o problema-raiz é consistir o resultado de "cin >> r0" (ou "buffer >> r0" em sua versão)...adicionalmente deve ser eliminada a chamada recursiva de pergunta1 para evitar leak de memória

Answer (score 0):

Repare na declaração da variável `r0`.
Analisando o `switch`, é possível inferir que você declarou a variável `r0` com o tipo `int`. Isso está ocasionando o *loop*.
Tente adaptar o seu código para o seguinte:

```
void pergunta1() {
    char r0;

    cin >> r0;

    switch (r0){
        case '1':
            pergunta2();
            break;
        case '2':
            pergunta2();    
            break;
        default:
            printf("Valor inválido!\n");
            pergunta1();
    }
}
```

Repare na declaração da variável `r0`, com o tipo `char`. E também na estrutura do `switch` que agora conta com aspas simples para validar os valores.

Comment: switch não causa loop...e no exemplo em questão a mudança que você sugeriu é inócua

Comment: Pode mostrar onde foi falado que o "switch" está causando o loop? E ao contrário dos que você afirma, execute os dois códigos e verifique se a alteração que sugeri não corrige o problema relatado. Antes de negativar, teste o código..

Comment: você tem razão, realmente mudando para o tipo de r0 para char corrige o loop, mas considero isso um remendo, porque a causa raiz do problema é uma conjunção de 2 fatores: a não verificação do resultado do "cin >> r0", e o uso de recursividade...nesta situação, quando for digitado alguma coisa que nao for número o programa entra em loop infinito...leitura de teclado é uma tarefa notoriamente difícil para iniciantes tanto em C quanto C++...editei minha resposta para colocar uma solução robusta da pergunta

Comment: (edite sua resposta para que eu possa tirar o voto negativo)

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE

Colocando aqui uma versão robusta do programa que foi postado.

A causa raiz do problema (loop infinito) é uma conjunção de 2 fatores: a não verificação do resultado do "cin >> r0", e o uso de recursividade.

Nesta situação, quando for digitado alguma coisa não numérica o programa entra em loop infinito.

Leitura de teclado é uma tarefa notoriamente difícil para iniciantes tanto em C quanto C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static void pergunta2()
{
  cout << "* pergunta2\n";
}

static void pergunta1()
{
  int r0;
  string resto_da_linha;

  // loop de execucao de pergunta1
  for (;;) // #1
  {

    // leitura e consistencia da digitacao
    for (;;) // #2
    {
      cout << "* digite uma opcao: 1 ou 2: " << flush;
      if (cin >> r0)
      {
        // sucesso na leitura de um numero
        break;
      }
      cout << "* erro, digitacao invalida (digitar apenas numeros)\n";
      cin.clear(); // como houve erro na leitura, precisa limpar o estado de cin

      // cin.ignore(1000, '\n');    // opcao 1 para limpar o buffer de entrada
      getline(cin, resto_da_linha); // opcao 2 para limpar o buffer de entrada
    } // for #2

    // por via das duvidas limpa o buffer de leitura,
    // caso o usuario tenha digitado coisas demais
    // cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    getline(cin, resto_da_linha);

    switch (r0)
    {
      case 1:
        pergunta2();
        break;
      case 2:
        pergunta2();
        break;
      default:
        cout << "\n* erro, opcao invalida\n\n";
        break;
    } // switch
  } // for #1
} // pergunta1

int main()
{
  pergunta1();
}
```

Comment: No caso está "errado" só para o uso pretendido, afinal é perfeitamente normal (e muitas vezes necessário) usar o `switch` sem o `break` em uma ou mais condições caso o efeito cascata seja desejado. Comentei só para desmistificar a necessidade do break como regra universal, caso um principiante venha a ler o post. - Quanto ao uso recursivo da função, realmente é muito suspeito. Parece péssima idéia, mas sem ver os requisitos do autor, fica difícil saber.

Comment: @Bacco é discutível se é "perfeitamente normal" o uso de switch sem break, tanto assim que se recomenda documentar que é de propósito que o break não foi usado

Comment: Não acho que haja muito a discutir - Se não fosse normal o `case` seguinte já o faria naturalmente. O break é separado do case seguinte justamente para que se use somente quando necessário. O problema é que as pessoas não entendem que o `switch` (e o `break`) funcionam de maneira análoga ao `goto` e não a uma estrutura `if` `elseif` `else` (esse engano eu vejo em muito material internet afora). Duas coisas que são poderosas e mal ensinadas em programação são `switch` e máquinas de estado.

Comment: Usar case sem break é conhecido como fall through e pelo que eu saiba seu uso é natural desde os anos 80, quando comecei a programar em C.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques "natural" baseado em que parâmetro ? se for pela quantidade de vezes que se usa case sem break vs com break, então eu não considero "natural"

Comment: @bacco fallthrough não é o caso de uso "normal", tanto assim que no C++17 foi criado um atributo para este caso https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough

Comment: Para a estrutura da função pergunta1 apresentada, fica nítido que o uso recursivo não interfere no processo. Esta não seria a estrutura de código que eu utilizaria, mas não cabe aqui discutir o melhor método para construir essa função.

Comment: @E. Thomas: na verdade, o uso de recursividade neste caso é um dos fatores que causa o loop infinito no programa que foi postado